# Lost emails at hoster

Tags: microsoft-outlook

It sounds unbelievable but my hoster (a large European hoster) lost all my mails. Some days ago to any reason he changed the IMAP and SMTP server address and my mails including folder structure disappeared from Outlook and iOS.

To proof that I did not use local folders in Outlook but IMAP folders as accused by the hoster  I could make a screenshot from my second PC before synchronizing for new. Then he told me that the backup did not include any folders on the server and no mails. I insisted that could not be possible because why should I delete my 1000s business mails. After that suddenly he backed up the folder structure which was accused to be local folders. But the mails are still not backed up. I told them to take a backup one month ago to get all my mails back. He only have back ups for 7 days... unbelievable.

Now, I exported the xy.ost file to xy.pst and opened this xy.pst. But to my surprise only the folder structure is visible - no mail at all. Although before that the export routine went through all folder and seemed to export all mails from xy.ost!!
What did happen there and why I can't export my mails which I still can see on the 2nd PC which was not synchronized.

Thx Michael

Comment: What's the size of the .ost file? Is it even sufficient size to actually contain 1000+ email bodies? Note that I am no expert on this topic.

Comment: Most large operations make periodic backups of data and disk images and some send them off-site for storage. You would need to get the cooperation of the host, or take legal action, to get access to the backups, and you might need to pay for access to that storage, but your mail should be mostly recoverable.  In the future, do not rely entirely on a third party to store your data -- make *local* copies of important mail.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by using a third party SW MailStore which made an export from my xy.ost to a xy.pst which contained ALL mails in my previous file structure.
What I do not understand is why the export option in OL 2019/2021 does not do the same but only exports the structure visible! As the size of the xy.pst file is very similar to the one produced by MailStore I suppose the mails would be also included but are not visible within the folders to any reason.

Although I am to have solved my issue finally, the question is, **why does OL not export an ost to pst with all mails visible??**

@DrMoishePippik: No, 2nd level support of the hoster told me that they do not make periodic back ups, only 7 days!!! Unbelievable.
So I will change to another hoster as this a no-go for me.
Looking up the contract with the hoster it does NOT say anything about the short interval of backing up!! In my opinion this is a case for the consumer protection agengy. This is absolut careless.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).